# How to interpret 3 outputs of Precision?

Tags: machine-learning, data

Say im running a classification Machine learning algorithm,

of 2 classes 0 & 1.

A 0 label is detecting a visitor/row did not Convert. while 1 label is detecting a visitor/row did Convert.

When the Precision Score of the model is 0.89.

And the Precision of Label 0 is 1.00 & the Precision of Label 1 is 0.51.

Can someone explain what each of these 3 results mean?

Does it mean that our model predicts a visitor will convert 89% of the time?

It correctly predicted which visitors would convert 51% of time, and predicted which visitors will NOT convert 100% of the time?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. This doesn't make sense to me: normally the positive class should be clearly specified. If it's not and we have only the precision for both classes (1 for class 0 and 0.51 for class 1) then what does "precision of the model" mean, and why is it different from the precision of any of the two classes? Unless "precision of the model" is actually micro- or macro-precision maybe, but that should be made clear.

Comment: Btw is this homework? If so please give the full text of the exercise, explain what you tried and what you don't understand.

Comment: no, this is not a homework excercise, but for a personal project. Please see the image of the output attached above that is underlined. @Erwan

Comment: And the  Precision Score from the Sklearn.Metrics is 0.89, .... this is the same thing as a precision of the model right?

Comment: This is very strange: the recall 1 for class 0 means that all the true 0 instances are correctly predicted as 0. Yet the precision 0.51 for class 1 means that half the instances predicted as 1 are not 1, so they must be 0. Also the accuracy cannot be 1 unless all the instances are correctly predicted. This is inconsistent, there must be a mistake in how you evaluate. That's probably also the reason why you get this 0.89 precision, also inconsistent with these values. Can you add the code that you run to obtain these results?

Comment: which part of the code?

Comment: Oh wait I was wrong about my previous point, I see what happens now: class 1 is so small that the rounding at 2 digits causes recall to be 1 even though it's actually something like 0.999. However this doesn't explain the "precision score of the model" of 0.89, this one must have been obtained differently. I'll write an answer about your main question.

Answer (score 2):

The first step to understand some classification results is to look at the confusion matrix (can be obtained with sklearn with [`confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)). Yours probably looks similar to this:

|  | predicted as 0 | predicted as 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true 0 | 554650 | 27 |
| true 1 | 634 | 28 |

Note that the rows sum to the total number for each true label: 554650+27=554677 for label 0, 634+28=662 for label 1. The columns sum to the total number for each predicted label.

If we focus on class 0 as the "positive class", we have:

- 554650 True Positive (TP) instances, i.e. correctly predicted positive instances
- 27 False Negative (FN) instances, i.e. positive instances wrongly predicted as negative
- 634 False Positive (FP) instances, i.e. negative instances wrongly predicted as positive
- 28 True Negative (TN) instances, i.e. correctly predicted negative instances

Now we can apply the precision formula:

$$P_0=\frac{TP}{TP+FP}=\frac{554650}{554650+634}=0.9989$$

It's rounded as 1 in the classification report.

We can do the same thing but this time considering class 1 as the positive class. This means that the numbers are different:

- 554650 TN
- 27 FP
- 634 FN
- 28 TP

Same formula with different numbers:

$$P_1=\frac{TP}{TP+FP}=\frac{28}{28+27}=0.509$$

Rounded as 0.51 in the classification report.

So the first point to understand is that the result is different depending on which class is considered as the positive class. Usually the minority class is selected as positive, here class 1, so the relevant results are the precision and recall for class 1.

- The precision score represents the proportion of correctly classified instances **among the instances predicted as positive**.

Precision doesn't say anything about instances which are *not* predicted as positive. For that there is recall:

- The recall score represents the proportion of instances which are correctly classified as positive **among all the truly positive instances**.

> When the Precision Score of the model is 0.89.

This is incorrect, according to these results the precision for the minority class is 0.51. 0.89 must have been obtained with some different data.

> Does it mean that our model predicts a visitor will convert 89% of the time?

No that's not what precision mean at all, see above: the precision scores says that *among the visitors that the model predicts they will convert*, 51% of them actually do.

> It correctly predicted which visitors would convert 51% of time, and predicted which visitors will NOT convert 100% of the time?

Not really, because you don't take into account recall. Among the visitors who actually convert, many of them are predicted as not converting by the model: the model predicts correctly only 4% of the visitors who actually convert. However it is correct that almost 100% of the visitors who don't actually convert are correctly found by the model.

For the record this data is strongly imbalanced: the minority class represents only 0.1% of the instances. It's much harder to reach a high performance with this kind of imbalance.